# Using Nested for loops to make a doubling then halfing pyramid

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

```
                 1
               1 2 1
             1 2 4 2 1
           1 2 4 8 4 2 1
         1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
      1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
   1 2 4 8 16 32 64 32 16 8 4 2 1 
1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

I need to make this pyramid using nested for loops,
so far all I have figured out is that I need three for loops. 
I know how for loops work and have a pretty good grasp on the fundamentals of java, but I have no earthly idea on how this works.

Comment: Doing the middle column should b really easy.  So is doing the part of each row right to the middle column.  Once you've got that, it is only a matter of mirroring the numbers to get the left half and you are done.  It will probably be easiest if you first build each row internally in an array and only print it if you have all the numbers there.  Use –1 or another “impossible” value to mark empty fields.

Comment: Try something, and then show us!

Comment: I think you'll actually need four for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this without debug but it should produce this pyramid:

```
      0       
    0 1 0    
  0 1 2 1 0  
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
```

```html
int pyramidHeight = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < pyramidHeight;i++){
  for(int j = 1; j < pyramidHeight*2;j++){
    if( j < pyramidHeight - i || j > pyramidHeight + i ){
      System.out.print(" ");

    }
    else{
      System.out.print(i - Math.abs(pyramidHeight - j));
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

With two simple changes you should get your pyramid.

Comment: This helped more than you know. I wondered if implementing an if statement to switch the operator was the key to this program, but after talking to my lab partner decided against it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This should work! Note that you have each row counting total 2*i+1 elements where i is your current row number.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

        int lim = 5;
        int spaceLim = lim*2;

        for (int i=0; i < lim; i++){ // Number of rows is the key here (pow 2)

            String s = "%" + spaceLim + "s";
            System.out.printf(s, "");
            if (i == 0){
                System.out.print(1);
            }
            else{
            for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%1.0f ",(Math.pow(2.0, (double)(j))));
            }

            for (int j=i; j>=0; j--){
                System.out.printf("%1.0f ", (Math.pow(2.0, (double)(j))));
            }

            }
            System.out.println();
            spaceLim -= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The demo of working solution is here - http://ideone.com/J2fcQw

Comment: My lab partner and I attempted something similar and had the same problem with the middle numbers duplicating. Other than that its fine, but I can't seem to get it to not print with .0 after every Int and to not print the middle number twice.

Comment: @RobbieTraverseParmentier      It doesn't print any duplicate middle number. I actually liked moloney55's solution as he used only 1 for loop, but the algorithm above has O(N) scaling i.e. total N rows to process for getting the pyramid.